# Python Check day entered by user

Tags: linux, python, date

Can you help make my python script check what day of the week corresponds to the date entered by the user?
I don't know how to create the script.

For example, if the user inputs a date of `22-11-2016`, the output should be `tuesday`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse and validate the user input of course, but here is one way:

```
from datetime import date

dt = date(2016, 11, 22)

print(dt.strftime("%A"))

dt = date.todate()

print(dt.strftime("%A"))
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html